# Bitbucket Build Status of Pull Request showing failed builds

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

after each build, I am getting the build status from Jenkins, but when I open in bitbucket Pull Request page it shows failed status in the row. How to change the setting to show the recent build status?

Same issue - [Bitbucket Build Status of Pull Request showing failed builds, instead of latest build status](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70605000/12891326)

please help.

Comment: I would amend the head commit with `git commit --amend -m 'new commit msg here'`, then run `git push -f` to run the pipeline again.

Comment: Couple questions, Bitbucket Cloud or Server? Jenkins freestyle jobs or pipelines?

Comment: Bitbucket server, pipeline @IonutS